# taking more than one cells into one cell

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am using a linq query to obtain a table of customers with their total money amount for each monetary unit exist in my database(this one is ok.)
when show the result of my query with Microsoft Report Viewer the result is like Table 1 but what i want is Table 2, only the customer name like "A" and a cell with all the monetory unit records > 0.

Is there any way you can suggest?

This is my code which produces Table 1:

```
var query = from kur in kurToplamlist                        
                    join cariBilg in db.TBLP1CARIs
                                  on kur.CariIdGetSet equals cariBilg.ID
                    select new
                    {
                        cariBilg.ID,//customerid
                        EUROBAKIYE = cariBilg.HESAPADI,
                        cariBilg.K_FIRMAADI,//other column names
                        cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI,//other column names
                        cariBilg.K_FIRMATELEFON,//other column names
                        cariBilg.K_YETKILITELEFON,//other column names
                        AUDBAKIYE = cariBilg.B_CEPTELEFON,//other column names                            
                        MonetaryUnit = String.Concat(kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet.ToString(), kur.DovizTuruGetSet.ToString()),//concatenates "100" and "TL/USD etc."                          

                    };
```

What i want is to obtain Table 2 in the image 
Thank you in advance.

[Table image](http://img689.imageshack.us/i/tableaa.jpg/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var query = from kur in kurToplamlist
                    where kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet > 0
                    join cariBilg in db.TBLP1CARIs
                                  on kur.CariIdGetSet equals cariBilg.ID
                    select new
                    {
                        cariBilg.ID,
                        EUROBAKIYE = cariBilg.HESAPADI,
                        cariBilg.K_FIRMAADI,
                        cariBilg.K_YETKILIADI,
                        cariBilg.K_FIRMATELEFON,
                        cariBilg.K_YETKILITELEFON,
                        AUDBAKIYE = cariBilg.B_CEPTELEFON,
                        TLBAKIYE = String.Concat(kur.KurToplamMiktarGetSet.ToString(), kur.DovizTuruGetSet.ToString()),   


                    };
        var dfg = from qre in query
                  select qre.TLBAKIYE;

        var aq = (from qw in query
                  select new { 
                        qw.ID,
                        EUROBAKIYE = qw.EUROBAKIYE,
                        qw.K_FIRMAADI,
                        qw.K_YETKILIADI,
                        qw.K_FIRMATELEFON,
                        qw.K_YETKILITELEFON,
                        AUDBAKIYE = qw.AUDBAKIYE,
                        TLBAKIYE = String.Join(",", (from qre in query
                                                    where qre.ID == qw.ID
                                                    select qre.TLBAKIYE).Distinct())

                 }).Distinct();            

        return aq;
```

This is my answer.